# Reading line by line in Julia

Tags: file-io, julia

I am trying to read from a file where each line contains some integer

But when I gave like this

```
f=open("data.txt")
a=readline(f)
arr=int64[]
push!(arr,int(a))
```

I am getting

```
ERROR: no method getindex(Function)
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:120
```

Answer (score 6):

The error comes from `int64[]`, since `int64` is a function and you are trying to index it with `[]`. To create an array of `Int64` (note the case), you should use, e.g., `arr = Int64[]`.

Another problem in your code is the `int(a)` - since you have an array of `Int64`, you should also specify the same type when parsing, e.g., `push!(arr,parseint(Int64,a))`

Comment: What is the difference b/w int() and parseint()? I think int() seems to work in my case

Comment: @user567879 My bad, `int()` supports parsing strings as well. However, if you were to run the code on a 32-bit platform, it might not match the `Int64` type, whereas `parseint(Int64, str)` allows you to specify the type so it's still advantageous.

Comment: And you can say `arr=Int64[]` (note the capitalization)

Comment: ...but in general you should use `Int[]` as it generalizes appropriately between 32-bit and 64-bit.