# Reading a file into a 1d array in Julia

Tags: arrays, file, input, multidimensional-array, julia

I have a pretty simple text file of just numbers that looks like
0
1.57
3.14
This example has 3 numbers, but amount is fine. I'm trying to read these into a 1d array of Float 64's, so I tried the following.

```
function read_x_data(fname)
  f=open(fname)
  xarr=readdlm(f, Float64)
  print(xarr)
  xarr=sortperm(xarr)   
end
```

However, I get the error that sortperm has no matching method sortperm(::Array{Float64, 2}). I don't understand why this is happening- how can I read my data into a 1d array instead? I saw a similar question at [Reading line by line in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859933/reading-line-by-line-in-julia), but I believe that using push n times like that is very inefficient, right? Any help with my problem or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your immediate question: `vec` will reshape any array into a 1d vector.

`sortperm` returns the permutation but not the original data; hence your example, even if you added `vec(xarr)`, would throw away the data. You probably want `sort`.

Finally, in Julia `push!` is not inefficient. You may be expecting it to be inefficient from experience with another language (Matlab?), but in Julia you can efficiently grow 1d arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to sort the data, this might work for you.

```
read_x_data(fname) = sort!(vec(readdlm(fname,Float64)))
```